# Deselecting the cell in cellForItemAt when selecting cell in didSelectItemAt

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a variabel `selectedIndexPath`, which gets the `indexPath` selected from previous view controller. I am getting the required `backgroundColor` for `cell` in the `collection view` of present view controller. But when I select another cell in the collection view, the selected cell of previous view controller remains same without being deselected. So, now I have two cells with the background color. Following is my code

```
var selectedIndexPath = IndexPath()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    self.collectionView.allowsSelection = true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TestCollectionViewCell

    if (indexPath == selectedIndexPath)
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false 
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
}
```

How do I `deselect` the cell in `cellForItemAt`, when I `select` new cell in `didSelectItemAt`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all set `allowsMultipleSelection` in Interface Builder and remove all redundant occurrences of setting it in code

You have to update the `selectedIndexPath` variable. Manipulating the cell directly is always a bad idea.
Reloading the cells is much more reliable.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    guard selectedIndexPath != indexPath else { return }
    let indexPathsToUpdate = [selectedIndexPath, indexPath]
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath            
    tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPathsToUpdate, with: .none)
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    guard selectedIndexPath == indexPath else { return }
    selectedIndexPath = IndexPath()
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

There is only one problem: If you want to have an empty selection you have to declare `selectedIndexPath` as optional and handle it properly.

Comment: Appreciate it. That makes sense :)

Comment: It works well but the only problem is that if you select the same cell twice and then select another cell, it is not working and throwing an error at collectionView.reloadItems(at: indexPathsToUpdate) in didSelectItemAt

Comment: I know, that's the problem I mentioned. I would drop `didDeselectItemAt` and use only `didSelectItemAt`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to override didDeselect for this. All you need to do is deselect the previously selected item while selecting the current item in **didSelectItem**. For that you can choose to maintain states in the cell as:

```
func changeToSelectedState() {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}

func changeToUnselectedState() {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

Or you can choose to write the same in the controller itself. And then you need to perform the deselection and selection in the following manner.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let previousSelectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
    previousSelectedCell.changeToUnselectedState()

    let currentCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    currentCell.changeToSelectedState()
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
}
```